# using PrimeFaces Selectors on non-jsf-components

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, primefaces

is it possible to do something like

```
<div class="refresh_#{bean.someId}">
   <h:panelGroup>
   ...
   </h:panelGroup>
</div>
```

and then somewhere

```
<p:commandButton update="@(.refreshAll_#{bean.someId})" />
```

I am thinking about how PFS works here.

I need this because I have some components which I want to update, but cannot set the id ( does not work, so I would just give them a class and update them later.

Will this work or is this a bad practise?

Comment: _"Will this work "_ Try... (and no, ypu cannot update non-jsf tags. Regardless of using PFS. Wrap them in e.g. a fragment tag

Comment: if you answer it as answer i can close this question. last thing: it will not be a problem to use as above EL in the update right?